# Magento Admin Nginx 404

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, nginx

I am migrating from Apache to Nginx magento. The site works fine but when I try to access the admin generates a 404.

```
www.mydomain.com/admin
```

This is the configuration that I have on my server

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    keepalive_timeout 300;
    access_log   logs/access.log;
    error_log    logs/error.log;
    location / {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
        }
        if ($uri ~* "\.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$") {
                expires max;
                break;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
            access_log        off;
            log_not_found     off;
            expires           30d;
    }
    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }
    location ~ .php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

        expires        off;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            deny all;
    }
    location /RequestDenied {
            return 500;
    }
    if ($bad_method = 1) {
            return 444;   
    }
}
```

**Versions**

1. Nginx/1.4.1
2. Magento 1.8
3. MySql 5.1.73

Comment: You can cleared cache? Made sure re-writes are on?

Comment: @Sebastian, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

What is set in your `app/etc/local.xml`

It should contain something like

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

If frontName is different use that to login in your admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the file off of a production server - Maybe you are missing your @handler items?

```
server {
    listen      80;

    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    keepalive_timeout   70;
    root        /var/www/vhosts/current/;
    index index.html index.php;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
        expires 30d;
    }
    location /app/                       { deny all; }
    location /includes/                  { deny all; }
    location /lib/                       { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/        { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/                   { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml          { deny all; }
    location /var/                       { deny all; }

    location /var/export/ {
        auth_basic              "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file    htpasswd;
        autoindex               on;
    }
    location  /. {
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ {
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires off;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 900s;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
    rewrite ^/minify/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/skin/m/([0-9]+)(/.*.(js|css))$ /lib/minify/m.php?f=$2&d=$1 last;

    location /lib/minify/ {
        allow all;
    }
    gzip on;
    #gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/xml text/css text/js application/x-javascript;
}
```

Comment: It does not work .
When I try to access
/index.php/admin/
I generated 404
When I access
/ admin /
redirects to
/index.php

Comment: you cleared cache, checked urls in database to make sure you don't have a custom?